# Can I use a 8Gb/s Fiber Channel HBA in a 4Gb/s system?

Tags: networking, storage-area-network, fiber, hba

Simple question: Is it possible to use a 8Gb/s Fiber HBA card with a 4Gb/s system?
Is there some technical documentation about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should you mean: Can I connect with a 8Gb/s HBA to a 4Gb/s device/FC switch, then the answer is yes, without a problem, and also to a 2Gb/s device etc. It's basically the same as with ethernet: You can connect a GB ethernet card to a 10 Mbit hub if you like.

What kind of documentation are you looking for?

Comment: Hi Sven! Thanks for the fast answer. It's actually enough. I was just looking for a document saying what you just wrote... But thinking technically, it shouldn't be a problem.